# How to get the URI of a resource in Grails?

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

A very basic question. I want to provide URIs for some objects in my application. For example, a resource is available at:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/1
```

However, I'd like to serialize such a User object. This serialization should contain the public URI of the object itself. So for example, the model has a new method `serializeToSomething`, which would serialize:

```
id: 1
username: JohnDoe
email: johndoe@example.com
publicURI: http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/1
```

**How can I let the model instance know of its URL?**

<sub>Some notes:</sub>
<sub>This has to happen within the scope of the model, controller or service, and *not* within the view. Also I *don't* want to hardcode this.</sub>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the URL of the current page in Grails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400773/getting-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-grails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See related question [Can I use grails tag outside of GSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191800/can-i-use-grails-tag-outside-of-gsp)

Basically you can use `g.createLink` in a controller or service, and it will return a string. So you can do something like:

```
def uri = g.createLink(controller: 'user', action: 'show', id: user.id, absolute: true)
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll try it out tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I ended up serializing 3 things: `controller` name, `action` name (typically "show") and `id`. Then I used these three in `g.createLink` when displaying deserialized objects in a View.

Sure, this won't work if you need deserialized object for external usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url in a controller using

```
request.forwardURI
```

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400773/getting-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-grails) has been asked before