# How to retrieve the current visited page (controller+action) via spring security

Tags: grails, spring-security

- As you note , my question is not " how to check if a user is connected or not  ", but rather , the question explicitly is "how to check if a user is connected on specific page "

Concretely ,  How to retrieve the current Controller/action browsed by the `currentUser`

i have this solution using ajax, however , i thing that there is a lack of performance :

## JS(Report Url):

```
<script>
  var cName='${controllerName}';
  var aName='${actionName}';
  setInterval(function(){
         $.post('user/myurl',{c:cName,a:aName}); 
  },10000)     

</script>
```

## Controller:

```
def myurl(){
    def u=User.get(springSecurityService.currentUser.id)  
    u.lastUrl=params?.c+'/'+params?.a
    u.lastUrlUpdated=new Date()
    u.save()



}
```

### Is there a built-in solution via spring security 4 ?

Comment: Take a look at this question&answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400773/getting-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-grails

Comment: BRIEFLY, we want to have business logic has as input :"id of user ", give as output :  "url visited currently by this user" .