# I need referrer URI in Grails 2.x

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 2.4.4 and trying to get the browser url which loaded my grails app (referrer url) in my controller. I have searched SO and google already, looked in documentation but it seems like i'm searching for a mythical creature.

```
// inside my before interception
String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
println "referer= "+referer  // null
```

Anyone done this?

Comment: `request.getHeader('referer')`  not `request.getHeader('Referer')`

Comment: However, that's when the browser provides that header. Are you just trying to find the current url used to execute your controller action? E.g. what's displayed in the address bar?

Comment: yes i'm trying to find out the URL in the address bar for example user enters in browser: https://my.server.com/myapp/dashboard/456. I want to retrieve that url in "myapp" in my "auth" controller which is automatically called from my filters file: before intercept

Comment: This might help then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400773/getting-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-grails

Comment: FYI: i get null for getHeader('referer') on localhost. But getHeader('User-Agent') is populated with info. So it seems like there is a problem with obtaining the 'referer' on localhost...

Comment: That HTTP header is provided when there is an action which sets it. Such as a form post or redirect. Normal GET doesn't set it.